# how to make many separate c++ files:- CodeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks

I have been using codeblocks for just few days.What problem i am facing is that it ask me to create a project but I want don't want to make project rather I want to make separate C++ files like one of palindrome and other of some other algorithm,but when I try to make this in my active project it only executes **"Main"** file.So my question is how to make different files that don't have any connection.And one more thing is that I have to type all the header files everytime so how can I make one template so that every new file is in form of template.Thank you

Comment: Code::Blocks (like every IDE) insists that any file you write in it belongs to some project, but it does not insist that every file you write belongs to the same project. If you don't want to make projects, then don't use an IDE. Otherwise, make one project for each of your algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

The way I get around this problem is as follows:

- Create a project with a file containing int main()
- Add whatever other files you want - but be careful not to duplicate function names
- Put function prototypes of each of the other functions in the main file above the main function
- You can then call any functions in the project from main()

For example you may have many different functions you want to test - they can all be called from main() - comment out any functions you don't want to use at that time. 
Say you had two cpp files in a project - one called main_project.cpp and one called sample.cpp. sample.cpp has a function int tester(int num){/**...*/}. In your main_project.cpp insert the line int tester(int); above main() then add the line tester(5); (for example) within the body of main().